# React Okta Authentication served by express behind nginx

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, okta

So I have an app, (react client, express backend) that is behind an nginx proxy over with ssl.

But I when I try and authenticate through okta, I get a successful authentication and then when I go to redirect `const auth = await this.props.auth;
      auth.redirect({ sessionToken: this.props.sessionToken });` I get kicked back to authenticate again on oktas login page. It works in Firefox (most time) but never works in chrome or IE.

In Chrome I get warnings in the console about HPKP headers, so I'm thinking that's the cause but I'm not sure. But I don't know why it would be since it **should** be over ssl.

I'm not sure what kind of code to put it here because I'm not entirely sure the problem

Answer (score 0):

How is the token passed/stored?

HPKP = HTTP Public Key Pinning

It's a method of verifying that the supplied security certificate belongs to the specific web server you are connecting to, to mitigate against MITM attacks, forged certificates etc.

I've no experience of setting it up but it's all about passing the correct headers, there are several Nginx directives for proxying you should look at, as Nginx doesn't pass all headers by default, or you may have to rewrite some. `proxy_redirect`, `proxy_set_header` and `proxy_pass_header` are probably good places to start.

Could be tricky as HPKP exists to stop anyone getting between the client and the server, and proxies exist to get between the client and the server. Do let me know what happens.